# Making icons configurable in a json file and using it in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, icons

I have an object **iconProps** in which I specified the class names of the fontawesome icons for specific attributes and use it in my react component . But it is limited to only fontawesome free icons . Is there anyway I can use many icons from multiple libraries like using react-icons https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons and making it configurable. Its little bit tricky I guess.

```
const iconProps = {
    "id": "fas fa-id-card" ,
    "mobile" : "fas fa-phone",
    "name": "fas fa-user",
    "gender": "fas fa-venus-mars",
    "marital_status": "fas fa-ring" ,
    "birth_date": "fas fa-calendar-alt"
}
```

using in component like

```
<div> <i className= {iconProps.id} />The id : 23456</div>
```